# C# - Regex replace any character using dot . in bracket [ ]

Tags: c#, regex, replace

Example:

```
string str = "Example[1]";
string output = Regex.Replace(str, "[.]", "");
```

But it doesnt work, the output is still: Example[1]

I though the result will be "Example" only?

Please help :(

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i expected my output will be:  Example

Comment: You should escape the `[` at least, because this way it only matches a single `.`. See: `\\[.\\]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct.. just use escape characters for brackets..

```
string output = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[.\]", "");
```

**Output**: Example

**EDIT**: if you have more than one characters in brackets.. use `"\[.+?\]"`

Comment: I tried .+ but it not working, example i have "ExampleOne[10] ExampleTwo[11]", the result will be "ExampleOne". Any character after ExampleOne will be remove. I expected the result will be "ExampleOne ExampleTwo"

Comment: ^ Yes, this is perfect! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the following expression:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(str, @"\[\d+\]", "");
```

It looks for symbol `[`, any number of digits and symbol `]`